# How to count and rank within field? SQL

Tags: sql

```
| proj_id | list_date  | state ||
|   1     |   03/05/10 |   CA   |
|   2     |   04/05/10 |   WA   | 
|   3     |   03/05/10 |   WA   | 
|   4     |   04/05/10 |   CA   | 
|   5     |   03/05/10 |   WA   | 
|   6     |   04/05/10 |   CA   |
```

What query could I write so that I can count how many projects were listed in each month by state? Using MySQL

Comment: What is the context? Field Name and Data Type of what?

Comment: It's a hypothetical table. The field names are project_id, list_date, and state_name. What query could i write to show how many projects were listed in each month by state?

Comment: When you write a question, be sure to be clear as to what you're asking. If you include more information in the original question, you might get an answer instead of being downvoted (i.e. edit your question above)

Comment: Share some input data with expected output. Also, what DBMS are you using? `sql` is just a language.

Comment: hey there! I just fixed it - I hope that's okay

Comment: What is your dbms name

Comment: my DBMS is MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this? How many projects a month per a state.

```
SELECT project_id, list_date, state_name, COUNT(*) As Projects FROM projects GROUP BY MONTH(list_date), state_name;
```

Here is the sql fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/194dd9/1

Edit:

If you meant you want to count EACH project per month (meaning there could be multiple entries of the same project_id) then this fiddle does that:

```
SELECT project_id, list_date, state_name, COUNT(*) As Projects FROM projects GROUP BY MONTH(list_date), state_name, project_id;
```

and the fiddle for this one:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd5803/4

Comment: I just tried this - it looks like the states are not aggregating together. For example, it will list out 2 Projects Nevada and another 3 Projects in Nevada. How do you make the query show 5 Projects in Nevada?

Comment: @JuniorSQL Have a look at this one http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/194dd9/1 thats showing how many projects per state.

Comment: @JuniorSQL Because those are different months some are in 2013 other in 2018. Your question asked how many each month by state.

Comment: this has been extremely helpful - last question, how could i get rid of the project_id column, and just show month, state and the number of Projects?

Comment: @JuniorSQL Thanks! If you feel this was an acceptable answer if you could click the checkmark next to the answer to help others if they see this as well.

Comment: What if I had another field in the table that was project_status and it contained  Finished or Unfunished? How could i determine the percentage of projects in each month and state that have been finished?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
SELECT * INTO #temp
FROM(
    SELECT 1 AS project_id,  Getdate() list_date , 'U.P' state_name  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS project_id,  DATEADD(MONTH,-2,Getdate()) list_date , 'M.P' state_name  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS project_id, Getdate() list_date , 'U.P' state_name  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS project_id,  DATEADD(MONTH,-5,Getdate()) list_date , 'R.J' state_name  
) AS T

SELECT * FROM #temp

SELECT COUNT(T.project_id) AS TotalPorject, CONVERT(varchar(10),T.list_date) AS ProjectDate, t.state_name   FROM #temp T
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10),T.list_date), t.state_name
```

Comment: Hi Sanjay - thanks for your quick response. How come we don't use a count function?

Comment: @JuniorSQL not sure, please visit on this link might it helps you.https://codingsight.com/methods-to-rank-rows-in-sql-server-rownumber-rank-denserank-and-ntile/

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

```
SELECT MONTH(list_date), state_name, COUNT(proj_id) As projectcount
FROM projects 
GROUP BY MONTH(list_date), state_name
```